# Filter sqlalchemy sqlite datetime column by date

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a datetime column in a database (Named TestBase) like so:

```
INDEX   DateTimeColumn
...     ...
1241    2010-07-26 07:04:05 
1242    2010-07-26 07:04:07 
1243    2010-07-26 07:04:12 
1244    2010-07-27 10:59:53
```

I want to get all the unique days in the column.

However, using the distinct function in sqlalchemy as such: `distinct(TestBase.DateTimeColumn)` does not work. As it takes the time within the timestamp into account and considers every entry to be unique.

How do I write a query which ignores the time within a timestamp and just returns the list of unique dates?

Comment: Are you using the ORM or the Core API?

Comment: I am using ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the database's `DATE` function to truncate the datetime to a date.  The `DATE` function is accessed through `sqlalchemy.sql.func`:

```
from sqlalchemy import sql

q = session.query(sql.func.date(MyModel.datetimecolumn))
```